# Reversing groups of lines in bash

Tags: bash, reverse

I'm looking for an elegant method for reversing a text file content, not just line by line (as tac do) but by groups of line (sections). The following example should be exhaustive:

Original file content:

```
--------    -----
    time        |
--------        | 
10:00:00        |--- section 1 
10:00:10        | 
10:00:20        |
--------    -----
--------    -----
    time        |
--------        | 
10:01:00        |--- section 2 
10:01:10        | 
10:01:20        |
--------    -----
```

Desidered output:

```
--------    -----
    time        |
--------        | 
10:01:00        |--- section 2 
10:01:10        | 
10:01:20        |
--------    -----
--------    -----
    time        |
--------        | 
10:00:00        |--- section 1 
10:00:10        | 
10:00:20        |
--------    -----
```

Comment: To be more accurate, the solution should take as input the numer of line and reverse it. As an example, tac reverse line by line just as the input passed is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One awk could do:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0};/-----/{++j};j==3{t="";for(k=0;k<i;++k)t=t a[k]"\n";b[++l]=t;i=j=0}END{for(i=l;i;--i)printf "%s", b[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
date        time        hostname    cpu     ram     /       /opt
----------------------------------------------------------------
2013/09/08  15:40:00    server1     20%     30%     50%     70%
2013/09/08  15:40:00    server2     15%     21%     49%     72%
2013/09/08  15:40:00    server3     20%     40%     40%     75%
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
date        time        hostname    cpu     ram     /       /opt
----------------------------------------------------------------
2013/09/08  15:35:00    server1     15%     30%     50%     70%
2013/09/08  15:35:00    server2     18%     21%     49%     72%
2013/09/08  15:35:00    server3     15%     40%     40%     75%
----------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------
date        time        hostname    cpu     ram     /       /opt
----------------------------------------------------------------
2013/09/08  15:30:00    server1     20%     30%     50%     70%
2013/09/08  15:30:00    server2     10%     21%     49%     72%
2013/09/08  15:30:00    server3     15%     40%     40%     75%
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another safer variation which could exclude invalid data:

```
awk '/^-----+$/{++j};!j{next};{a[i++]=$0}j==3{t="";for(k=0;k<i;++k)t=t a[k]"\n";b[++l]=t;i=j=0}END{for(i=l;i;--i)printf "%s", b[i]}' file
```

Another one that bases on number of lines:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0}i==7{t="";for(k=0;k<i;++k)t=t a[k]"\n";b[++l]=t;i=0}END{for(i=l;i;--i)printf "%s", b[i]}' file
```

A little simpler:

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0}i==7{t="";for(i=0;i<7;++i)t=t a[i]"\n";b[++j]=t;i=0}END{for(;j;--j)printf "%s", b[j]}' file
```

And another simple way to do it in Bash with same concept:

```
( IFS=$'\n'; while read -r A[I++]; do [[ I -eq 7 ]] && { B[++J]="${A[*]}"; I=0; }; done; for ((;J;--J)); do echo "${B[J]}"; done; ) < file
```

Another *true* one-liner for Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$stdin.readlines().each_slice(7).entries.reverse.each { |b| puts b; }' < file
```

Comment: I'd like to have a solution not linked to the particular spacer, the input should be just the number of lines belonging to the section...

Comment: @Tom I made an update for that.

Comment: @Tom I added a Bash solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with standard commands, using temporary files. And it's even shorter, and more readable in my opinion :)

```
split -a 4 -d -l 7 data.txt block
cat $(ls -r block*) > reversed-data.txt
rm block*
```

For `split` command :

- `-a 4` is for suffixes of 4 numbers
- `-d` is for numerical suffixes
- `-l 7` split the source file by this number of lines
- `data.txt` file to read
- `block` prefix of temporary files

`split` generates a temporary file for each block of lines, named `blocknnnn` where `nnnn` is a sequence number. `cat` puts the blocks together, with the list of files in reverse order, as `ls -r` gives it.

Advantage : the file is not loaded into memory, so there is no limit to its size on this front

Drawback : a full copy of data is copied to disk, so you need twice the space

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is definitely the right way to go, but here is a bash alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

separator='----------------------------------------------------------------' # each block must end with a separator
blockSeparators=3 # number of separators in each block. Could be 1 as well

dataArr=()
current=0
subCounter=0
while read -r curLine; do
    dataArr[current]+=$curLine$'\n'
    if [[ $curLine == "$separator" ]]; then
        (( ++subCounter == blockSeparators )) && (( current++ , subCounter=0 ))
    fi
done < file.txt

for (( i=${#dataArr[@]}; i>=0; i-- )); do
    echo -n "${dataArr[i]}"
done
```

And if you know that all of your blocks have exactly 7 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

blockLines=7

dataArr=()
current=0
lineCounter=0
while read -r curLine; do
    dataArr[current]+=$curLine$'\n'
    (( ++lineCounter == blockLines )) && (( current++ , lineCounter=0 ))
done < file.txt

for (( i=${#dataArr[@]}; i>=0; i-- )); do
    echo -n "${dataArr[i]}"
done
```

But as already stated, use `awk` solution. Bash is not a right thing to do such manipulations :)

## Edit:

Even shorter in bash!

```
blockSize=7

readarray lines < file.txt
for (( i=${#lines[@]}-blockSize; i>=0; i-=blockSize )); do
    ( IFS=''; echo -n "${lines[*]:i:blockSize}" )
done
```

Comment: As already stated, think the separator (---------) as just a normal line of the file. The solution should take a number of lines and reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my bash solution

```
tmparr=()
blockSize=7
i=$blockSize
tac file | while read line; do  
tmparr[$i]="$line" && ((i--))  
[ $i -eq 0 ] && i=$blockSize && for j in "${tmparr[@]}"; do echo "$j"; done
done
```